# How to Remove Space Between Items in GridView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

How to Remove Space Between Items in GridView in Flutter? I want to remove space between items. How can I do that?

```
GridView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    itemCount: list.length,
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 0,
      mainAxisSpacing: 0,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Text(list[index]);
    }),
```

what I have,

```
lorem                 ipsum



dolor                 sit
```

what I want,

```
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView's items always have a same width and height and it's value depends on the parameter value of the Delegate.

A width is 'screen widht / crossAxisCount' and a height is mainAxisExtent or depends on childAspectRatio.
(In your case, you are not use the mainAxisExtent and childAspectRatio. So the height of item is same with the width.)

If you wrap the Text item in Colored Container, you can see the screen like the picture below.

[image]

So, if you want to move the position of text in a GridView, you should wrap the Text in Align with your own rules.

Comment: However, I can't give you an example because i don't understand what is your detailed purpose.